# Compiler not indicating an argument can't be assigned to a parameter

Tags: typescript

I am working in a codebase where `"strictNullChecks": true,` is applied.

There is a function defined like:

`const applyConfigToDetails = (details: Details) => ...`

It is called with data retrieved from an Ajax call:

```
  .then({data}) => {
    applyConfigToDetails(data.metrics?.meta.details);
  }
```

`metrics` is possibly `null`, and both `meta` and `details` are typed to any. But given the optional chaining, the argument could be `null` - therefore I was expecting the compiler to complain, but it isn't!

I created a similar scenario in TS Playground and got an error close to what I was expecting:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why am I not getting an error indicating `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Details'`? Is there some other config or something I need to apply?

Comment: I suspect your `tsconfig.json` is being ignored. Take a look at the build output (in the Output window) to see which `tsconfig.json` is being used with `tsc`. Also, consider using `"strict": true` - as that enables other _essential_ (imo) checks including `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: "..and both `meta` and `details` are typed to `any`" <-- **here's your problem**. Using the `?.` operator in TypeScript will not evaluate to `any`, it will evaluate to `T | undefined`, so if you see `any` then that means someone has put `:any` somewhere. You need to find it and replace it with a more appropriate type. No-one should be using `any` in TypeScript anymore (use `unknown`). Expressions and values typed as `any` will not trigger `null` check warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Dai. However, `metrics` is strongly typed,  only `meta` and `details` are typed to `any`. I'll have to check the config per your first comment. Interesting you mention there is no use case for `any` anymore, I had not heard that. I know `unknown` is a more restrictive top-level type, but I hadn't heard it could replace `any` entirely.

Comment: The fact that `metrics` has a defined-type is irrelevant, if `meta` and `details` are `any` then that's still the reason why. **Using the `any` type will disable `null` checks**. There is no such thing as "`any-but-not-null`" - it's as simple as that. (If you do want to express "not `null` and not `undefined` then use the empty-type: `{ }`).

Comment: I'll admit that there are still some _limited_ uses for `any` when used as type for a local-variable for _quick-hacks_ when interacting with parts of the DOM or libraries with old or incorrect `.d.ts` files and you don't have the time to manually fix the `d.ts` files. Type-guard functions should use `unknown` for their parameters (assuming a better type wasn't already suitable). Inside a type-guard it's better to assert using the expected type instead of `any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a misunderstanding in what the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) does:

> instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`.

So if your `metrics` is `null`, the optional chaining returns `undefined`, not `null`. Hence your 2nd error message.

You may confuse it with how the [logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) works:

> returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all truthy.

So if it had been used instead of optional chaining (`metrics && metrics.meta`), then you may have `null`.